# Set a persistent global MySQL parameter

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, persist, my.ini

I set the following MySQL parameter:

```sql
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 2147483;
```

However, after server restart it reverted to its default value `28800`. Isn't the `SET` command persistent? In order to have this parameter persistent, should I edit a configuration file? Would that file be `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`? If so, is it simply:

```sql
wait_timeout=2147483
```

If so, which section should it be in `my.ini`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set global doesn't make persistent variables.

You should write that under **[mysqld]** section in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=86400
```

Comment: Is `my.ini` the Windows equivalent of linux's `my.cfg`?

Comment: Yes, Mysql on Windows searches several places for settings file in this order: %WINDIR%\my.ini, %WINDIR%\my.cnf, C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf, INSTALLDIR\my.ini, INSTALLDIR\my.cnf

Comment: See [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200825/mysql-config-both-for-global-and-for-session)

Answer (score 0):

You can persist [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) (global variable) to be `2147483` with the SQL below. *The SQL below only changes `wait_timeout` global variable rather than `wait_timeout` session variable and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html) explains how to persist global variables:

```sql
SET PERSIST wait_timeout = 2147483;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@PERSIST.wait_timeout = 2147483;
```

In addition, you can disable `wait_timeout` to persist with the SQL below. *The SQL below doesn't change `wait_timeout` global variable and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-persist.html) explains how to disable persisted global variables:

```sql
RESET PERSIST wait_timeout;
```

And, you can show `wait_timeout` persisted variable with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-persisted-variables-table.html) explains `persisted_variables` table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.persisted_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'wait_timeout';
```